# Find a point coordinate which is perpendicular and at a specific distance from line endpoint

Tags: java

I am developing a java application in which I have a line with coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Now i need to find a point (x3,y3) that is at a specific distance 'Z' from point (x2,y2) and is perpendicular to point (x2,y2). I need to find the coordinates of point (x3,y3). All i have is values of the end coordinates of line (x1,y1) , (x2,y2) and distance 'Z'. Please give me the formula to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: A point perpendicular to another point? Where did you learn geometrics? Also, the formula you need can easily be found on the internet with a little research. Last but not least, this has nothing to do with java and programming, therefore it is clearly off-topic here

Comment: Your question is not really about coding, it is about mathematics... You can find the formula by googeling some minutes!

Comment: A point  can't be perpendicular to another.  Please clarify what you actually mean.

Comment: Rafalon what i meant is a point(x3,y3) lies on the perpendicular axis at a distance 'Z' from point (x2.y2). the point is perpendicular to line.

Comment: dear deHaar i know how to solve this using compass and scale i need to know the formula so that i can implement this in my java code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming problem but mathematic.

Comment: @Arun I know what you mean, and I already knew it when I first posted my comment. The point is: if you can phrase your problem with the right terms, then you can google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have a line that goes through points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`.  I think what you mean is that you would like to find a point `(x3,y3)` that is perpendicular to the line that is defined by `(x1, y1)` and `(x2,y2)`, not

> perpendicular to point (x2,y2).

Recall the equation for a line: `y = mx + b`, where `m` is the slope and `b` is the `y`-intercept.  To get the equation for the line that is perpendicular to the first line, we create a line that has a slope that is the negative reciprocal of the first line.  For example, if we had a line defined by the equation `y = 2x`, the line that perpendicular to the first line would be defined by the equation `y = -1\2x`.  Now, you just need to use the Euclidean distance formula to find points that are your distance `Z` away from `(x2,y2)` and lie on the second, perpendicular line.

Comment: Thanks a lot parker i really appreciate your help. It would be really helpful if you could explain me the equations and terminology that you have used since i am very weak in maths.

Comment: I would recommend searching around and trying to understand these concepts thoroughly, as they are pretty important.

Comment: sure Parker. Thanks a lot.